# Can't run brew update

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew update`, I'm getting the error:

```
mkdir: /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks: Permission denied
Error: Can't create update lock in /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks!
Fix permissions by running:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew
```

And when I run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew` I get:

```
chown: /usr/local/var/homebrew: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

see  link for reference
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228